# how to store xml data in sql server database using xsl file

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, xslt

I m using embedded jquery api for fetching xml information from web the jquery transform this xml into xsl file for displaying data on page.

i want to save these data in my database sql server 2008.

my .xsl file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
Compatibility List:
- EmbeddedReprUrl-1.0.0.js-->

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/PageRepresentation">

    <![CDATA[<div class="embeddedUrlRepresentation" >]]>
    <![CDATA[<br/>]]>
    <![CDATA[<table border="1" style="border:1px solid Black; color:blue">]]>
    <![CDATA[<tr>]]>
    <![CDATA[<td> Video Url </td>]]>
    <![CDATA[<td>]]>
    <![CDATA[<a href="]]><xsl:value-of select="Url"/><![CDATA[" target="_blank">]]><xsl:value-of select="Url"/><![CDATA[</a></td>]]>
    <![CDATA[</tr>]]>
    <![CDATA[<tr>]]>
    <![CDATA[<td> Thumb Image Path </td>]]>
    <![CDATA[<td>]]><xsl:value-of select="Pictures/PagePicture[1]/Url"/><![CDATA[</td>]]>
    <![CDATA[</tr>]]>
    <![CDATA[<tr>]]>
    <![CDATA[<td> Video play url </td>]]>
    <![CDATA[<td>]]><xsl:value-of select="Videos/PageVideo[1]/VideoSources/PageVideoSources[1]/Url"/><![CDATA[</td>]]>
    <![CDATA[</tr>]]>
    <![CDATA[<tr>]]>
    <![CDATA[<td> Video Title </td>]]>
    <![CDATA[<td>]]><![CDATA[<a href="]]><xsl:value-of select="Url"/><![CDATA[" title="]]><xsl:value-of select="Title"/><![CDATA[" target="_blank">]]><xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="Title!='' and Title!='null'">
      <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="Url"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose><![CDATA[</a>
          </div>]]><![CDATA[</td>]]>
    <![CDATA[</tr>]]>
    <![CDATA[<tr>]]>
    <![CDATA[<td> Video Author Name </td>]]>
    <![CDATA[<td>]]><xsl:if test="AuthorName!='' and AuthorName!='null'">
      <xsl:value-of select="AuthorName"/>
    </xsl:if><![CDATA[</td>]]>
    <![CDATA[</tr>]]>
    <![CDATA[<tr>]]>
    <![CDATA[<td> Details </td>]]>
    <![CDATA[<td>]]><xsl:if test="Description!='' and Description!='null'"><xsl:value-of select="Description"/><![CDATA[</td>]]>
    </xsl:if>
    <![CDATA[</tr>]]>
    <![CDATA[</table>]]>
    <![CDATA[</div>]]>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this is displaying xml information on the page i want to save this information in the database. my query is
How to connect xsl file to sql databse and how to apply sql insert query in xsl file.
How to insert data from xsl to sql server database.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can just push a  some.xml file in to a database  :)

You will need some sort of back-end that will make the connection.
The common way to go is with [PHP](http://php.net/)
and functions like:

```
<?php
$serverName = "serverName";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"userName", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

//Errors and validatons are skipped to keep the example simple.

$sql = "INSERT INTO my_table  SET content = " . $xmlContent . ";
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare( $conn, $sql);
sqlsrv_execute( $stmt )
```

?>

Beware, Installing PHP with the needed configuration for SQL-SERVER is not easy!

This is one way to do it .. but you will have to read some more  :)